# Auth Laravel check authentication of user not working in custom controller

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have created a multi auth in Laravel using guards. I have added an 'admin' guard and login and all is working. Also if I look to auth states of different guards it is working correctly. If I load this calendar page, it returns auth true and also web or admin true depending on whose logged in.

```
Route::get('/availability/calendar', function () {
  return view('app', ['data' => ['auth' => Auth::check(), 'id' => Auth::user()- 
>id, 'authWeb' => Auth::guard('web')->check(), 'authAdmin' => Auth::guard('admin')->check()]]);
})->middleware('auth:web,admin');
```

But if I try to access Auth in a custom controller I created, it returns false for all: Auth::check() and also for the guards web and admin, false is returned. I do not understand why Auth is working in the web.php but not in my custom controller. Am I overlooking something, any help is appreciated!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CustomController extends Controller
{

    public function get_customStuff_api() {
        $returnData = [];
        $returnData ['auth'] = Auth::check();
        $returnData ['web'] = Auth::guard('web')->check();
        $returnData ['admin'] = Auth::guard('admin')->check();

        return response()->json($returnData);

    }
}
```

Comment: what middleware are assigned to the route that points to this controller method?

Comment: I did not assign any middleware, my api route looks like this: Route::get('/myStuff', 'CustomController@get_customStuff_api'); How should I assign middleware to it?

Comment: `php artisan route:list` you can see all the middleware assigned to any route ... "my api route" so `api.php`? ... which isn't for `web` its for stateless apis (out of the box)

Comment: Yes api.php. So how can I check if web or admin is authenticated?

Comment: its based on your auth configuration ... if you have set your guards to use `session` driver then you need sessions, which is provided by the `web` group of middleware ... no session, no auth in this case

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I also faced this problem.
I am using Laravel version 8.12 under PHP 8.0.5.
The way it worked for me is to add the following to the file **\app\Http\Kernel.php** :

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;
```

Then inside the **protected $middlewareGroups** property, inside the api middleware add: **EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,**
So it looks like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [

       // 'web' => ...

        'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```